# How to Troubleshoot Graphics Card/Driver problem in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, 14.04, radeon

I'm having issues with my old graphics card (ATI HD4850) on Ubuntu 14.04. I suspect it may just be getting old from running hot for so long, but I would like to make sure it's not a driver problem (open source radeon). I've read all kinds of posts about all kinds of command line ninja stuff, but which of those commands helps? Which command does what?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few useful commands and what they do:

**Check hardware acceleration and OpenGL**

This is where I usually start. If something gets messed up, like your old card no longer being supported by the current driver, it will usually show here first.

`/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
OpenGL vendor string:   X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV770
OpenGL version string:  3.0 Mesa 10.1.3
Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes
Unity 3D supported:       yes`

**Check Graphics Card ID and Installed Driver**

This is useful when you suspect your old card may no longer be supported, or you're simply not sure which specific variant of a graphics card you have, or you're not sure which driver you are running (open source or proprietary?). Run this command as `sudo`, you get more complete output.

`sudo lshw -c video
  *-display

       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RV770 [Radeon HD 4850]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:41 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fdce0000-fdceffff ioport:dc00(size=256) memory:fdcc0000-fdcdffff`

Driver support for ATI chips is listed by GPU code, not my graphcis card model number. Here we have the RV770 GPU and running the radeon (open source) driver.

**Which Version of the Driver Am I Running? Is It the Latest?**

That's 2 questions.
First, which version of the driver are you running. You need to know the name of the Ubuntu package. The output of the previous command told us the **driver** is called 'radeon', but the package name may be quite different. Use `apt` to search for an installed package containing the name 'radeon'. Use a wild-card (*) before and after to get everything and anything containing the word radeon.

`sudo apt-get update
sudo apt list --installed *radeon*
Listing... Done
libdrm-radeon1/now 2.4.67-1ubuntu0.14.04.1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 2.4.67-1ubuntu0.14.04.2]
xserver-xorg-video-radeon/trusty-updates,now 1:7.3.0-1ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed]`

This command found 2 installed packages, looks like the first one has an update available, the 2nd one doesn't say, suggesting it's up-to-date. To make sure, use `apt` to find the latest version.

`apt show xserver-xorg-video-radeon | grep -i version
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface yet. Use with caution in scripts.
Version: 1:7.3.0-1ubuntu3.1`

That's the version we have.